# How to find xml files and comment lines containing string 'dark'?

Tags: bash, awk

```html
<hello>
<world>dark</world>
</hello>
```

So far I have tried...

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do awk '{print "<!--"$0"-->"}' "$file"; done
```

... which fails.

But some how awk for a single file...

```
awk '{print "<!--"$0"-->"}' "$file"
```

... works just fine.

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover the condition *"to find xml files and comment lines containing string 'dark'"* exactly:

**`find`** + **`grep`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c \
'if grep -wq "dark" "$1"; then sed -i "s/.*dark.*/<!--&-->/" "$1"; fi' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better not use `awk`  for parsing XML files. Instead use an XML parser.

Here an example with `xmllint`:

```
find -name "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'xmllint --xpath "//*/world/text()" $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $1' _ {} \;
```

The `xpath` expression looks for the tag `<world>` nested in any other tag.

Comment: I didn't know xmllint. It seems to be what jq is for json parsing. Thanks for the tip.